# How can i send information to main activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I send MainActivity from the fragment, just like this:

I have a text on the fragment but it always different, for example:

```
byte[] bytes = editText.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
send(bytes); // It has to send to main MainActivity
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: please try the following answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make method in `MainActivity`

```
public void setData(byte[] bytes){
    // do what you want.
}
```

In your fragment call this method like this.

```
byte[] bytes = editText.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setData(bytes);
```

Answer (score 4):

**From fragment to activty:**

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

**From activity to fragment:**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```